# How to check whether application is launched by user or NSWorkspace

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have one Cocoa application and one launch agent. Launch agent launches application using 
`launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:` method call.
Inside my application I want to check application is launched by user(Normal launch) or is it launch agent launching my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you should be able to send an Apple Event via the additionalEventParamDescriptor: parameter of the launchAppWithBundleIdentifier: call and then receive that in your app so you know it's your agent launching you.

Comment: Thanks. I found the way to recieve. In my App delegate i wrote following method: `-(BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender
{
 NSAppleEventDescriptor *event = [[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager] currentAppleEvent];
 
 if (event)
 { AEEventID evtID = [event eventID];
  
  if (event && ( evtID == kAEOpenApplication) && [event eventClass] == kCoreEventClass) 
  {
   //Here some code
  } 
 }
 return YES;
}`

Comment: Great. I wasn't sure you how you would receive it but it sounds like you figured it out!

Comment: I asked a question about this strategy here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438168/how-to-send-and-receive-nsappleeventdescriptor-when-using-nsworkspace-to-open-ur