# Open a document with a specific application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript

I am trying to launch an app, and open a specific document with it.
For example, to launch Sublime Text, I can do it using the following call
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.sublimetext.3" options:(0) additionalEventParamDescriptor:nil
launchIdentifier:nil];

How do I pass a url of a document to the app, to make Sublime Text open this document after launch? I believe this can be done using additionalEventParamDescriptor, but I can't find an example anywhere on how to build a correct NSAppleEventDescriptor for an "open document" event.
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason for for using AppleEvents instead of NSWorkspace's `openFile:withApplication:`?

Comment: Thanks @red_menace. No reason, actually (but still curious how to do it via Apple Events)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send and receive NSAppleEventDescriptor when using NSWorkspace to open URLs between apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438168/how-to-send-and-receive-nsappleeventdescriptor-when-using-nsworkspace-to-open-ur)